# How can I display error from response ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, vue.js, vue-component

My script ajax like this :

```
this.$store.dispatch('changePassword', {password})
.then((response) => {
    console.log('resp')
    console.log(response)
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log('er')
    console.log(error)
});
```

I use vue component / vuex store

When the script run, the result on the tab console like this :

[image]

If I check in tab response in the tab network the result like this :

[image]

I want to get the value :

> The old password confirmation does not match.

I had console.log on the response / error, but I don't find the object

How can I get the value?

**Update** :

My vuex modules like this :

```
import { set } from 'vue'
import users from '../../api/users'
import * as types from '../mutation-types'
// initial state
const state = {
    addStatusChangePassword: null
}
// getters
const getters = {
    changePasswordStatus: state =>  state.changePasswordStatus,
}
// actions
const actions = {
    changePassword ({ dispatch,commit,state },{password})
    {
        return users.changePassword(password,
            data => {
                commit(types.CHANGE_PASSWORD_SUCCESS)
            },
            errors => {
                commit(types.CHANGE_PASSWORD_FAILURE)
            }
        )
    }
}
// mutations
const mutations = {
    [types.CHANGE_PASSWORD_SUCCESS] (state){
        state.addStatusChangePassword = 'success'
    },
    [types.CHANGE_PASSWORD_FAILURE] (state){
        state.addStatusChangePassword = 'failure'
    }
}

export default {
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations
}
```

My vuex api like this :

```
import Vue from 'vue'
export default {
    // api to change password
    changePassword (password, cb, ecb = null) {
        return axios.post('/member/profile/change-password', password).then(
            (resp) => {
                return resp.data;
            }, 
            (resp) => {
                return resp.data;
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the code for the `changePassword` action

Comment: It seems like your action is catching the error. It's hard to know what's going on without seeing that code.

Comment: @acdcjunior Look at my question. I had update it

Comment: @Mark_M Look at my question. I had update it

Answer (score 0):

In your `changePassword` You are passing your `data` forward, but you are:

- not differentiating errors (both paths of `changePassword` simply return the data); and also are
- ignoring the `data` and `errors` arguments in your action.

Changes below.

Add a proper `Promise` in your `changePassword`:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
export default {
    // api to change password
    changePassword (password, cb, ecb = null) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>                            // added       
          axios.post('/member/profile/change-password', password).then(
            (resp) => {
                resolve(resp.data);                                        // resolve()
            }, 
            (resp) => {
                reject(resp);                                         // reject() without .data
            }
         )
       );
    }
}
```

And, in your actions, also add the `Promise`:

```
// actions
const actions = {
    changePassword ({ dispatch,commit,state },{password})
    {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>                            // added       
         users.changePassword(password,
            data => {
               commit(types.CHANGE_PASSWORD_SUCCESS)
               resolve(data);                                                // forward
            },
            errors => {
               commit(types.CHANGE_PASSWORD_FAILURE)
               reject(errors);                                               // forward
            }
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: It's the same. It does not works. If I `console.log(resp)`, the result : `Error: Request failed with status code 422`

Comment: Check it out now. Using `reject(resp)` instead of `reject(resp.data)`

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, just a sec.

Comment: There you go, you had to add the promise to the action as well. Please try again.

Comment: What same? Can you be more specific?

Comment: Yes. The error same. `Error: Request failed with status code 422`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. You do know that 422 error is being cause server-side, right? I though you were wanting to display the error message, not get rid of it. To get rid of it, you must fix whatever the server is telling you to.

Comment: This problem seems to be resolved via the backend / server side. I will check it in the my backend